# Running migration from old branch in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I have a migration file in a Laravel project that sits on a slightly-older branch. In newer branches, newer migrations have been created and ran in production. I have ran the migration in my local environment, but in no other environment.

What will happen if I need to push this migration to the master branch, then to production? My assumption is that it will just not run since a newer migration has run, but that is an assumption.

What is the best way to handle something like this? I could not find anything clear in the laravel documentation for Laravel 5.6.

Comment: Depends - if you are connecting to a different schema (defined in .env) on your local machine than the application is connected to in production, then the migration will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My assumption is that it will just not run since a newer migration has run, but that is an assumption.

Laravel tracks which migrations it has run in the database's `migrations` table. If a migration is in the directory and hasn't been run before, it will get applied next time `artisan migrate` is run, regardless of the fact that "newer" migrations have already been run. The migration code is not inherently aware of dates; it's running the migrations in filename order, as you can see [in the relevant code.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php#L464)

Comment: That is good news, and thanks for the link to source!